# wordpress foundation accordion mobile submenu

Tags: javascript, jquery, wordpress, zurb-foundation

I am trying to integrate the accordion feature to wordpress menu.

i came across with a code but it didn't give me the full expectation(not really a js guru).

here is the html code:

```
<div class="off-canvas-wrap" data-offcanvas>
    <div class="inner-wrap">
        <nav class="tab-bar">
            <section class="left-small">
                <a class="left-off-canvas-toggle menu-icon" href="#"><span></span></a>
            </section>
        </nav>

        <aside class="left-off-canvas-menu">
            <ul class="off-canvas-list">
                <li><label>Foundation</label></li>
                <li><a href="#">Option 1</a></li>
                <li><a href="#" class="off-canvas-submenu-call">Option 2 <span class="right"> + </span></a></li>

                <ul class="off-canvas-submenu">
                    <li><a href="#">Sub menu 1</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Sub menu 2</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Sub menu 3</a></li>
                </ul>

                <li><a href="#">Option 3</a></li>
                <li><a href="#" class="off-canvas-submenu-call">Option 4 <span class="right"> + </span></a></li>

                <ul class="off-canvas-submenu">
                    <li><a href="#">Sub menu 1</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Sub menu 2</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Sub menu 3</a></li>
                </ul>

                <li><a href="#">Option 5</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Option 6</a></li>

            </ul>
        </aside>

    <section class="main-section">
    Content

    </section>

    <a class="exit-off-canvas"></a>

    </div>
</div>
```

and here is the jscript:

```
   $(document).foundation();
            $(".off-canvas-submenu").hide();
                $(".off-canvas-submenu-call").click(function() {
                     var icon = $(this).parent().next(".off-canvas-submenu").is(':visible') ? '+' : '-';
                     $(this).parent().next(".off-canvas-submenu").slideToggle('fast');
                     $(this).find("span").text(icon);
                });
```

this works perfectly only for a static page, also work a bit in wordpress but the stuggle is that when you click on item in the menu all the li with submenu opens instead of one at a time. take attention of the html structure of the menu:

```
<aside class="left-off-canvas-menu">
    <ul class="off-canvas-list">
        <li><label>Foundation</label></li>
        <li><a href="#">Option 1</a></li>
        <li><a href="#" class="off-canvas-submenu-call">Option 2 <span class="right"> + </span></a></li>

        <ul class="off-canvas-submenu">
            <li><a href="#">Sub menu 1</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Sub menu 2</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Sub menu 3</a></li>
        </ul>

        <li><a href="#">Option 3</a></li>
        <li><a href="#" class="off-canvas-submenu-call">Option 4 <span class="right"> + </span></a></li>

        <ul class="off-canvas-submenu">
            <li><a href="#">Sub menu 1</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Sub menu 2</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Sub menu 3</a></li>
        </ul>

        <li><a href="#">Option 5</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Option 6</a></li>

    </ul>
</aside>
```

the ul submenu is in the same level with the li menu.

in wordpress the ul.submenu is inside the parent li menu.

```
<aside class="left-off-canvas-menu">
    <ul class="off-canvas-list">
        <li><label>Foundation</label></li>
        <li><a href="#">Option 1</a></li>
        <li>
            <a href="#" class="off-canvas-submenu-call">Option 2 <span class="right"> + </span></a>
            <ul class="off-canvas-submenu">
                <li><a href="#">Sub menu 1</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Sub menu 2</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Sub menu 3</a></li>
            </ul>
        </li>
    </ul>
</aside>
```

the curent code is actually working a bit, but we don't want to open all the submemnu by only clicking a single li.

here is the [codepen](http://codepen.io/designsoutheast/pen/ZYERGo?editors=101)

Answer (score 0):

```
$(document).foundation();
$(".off-canvas-submenu").hide();
$(".off-canvas-submenu-call").click(function() {
            var icon = $(this).parent().find(".off-canvas-submenu").is(':visible') ? '+' : '-';
            $(this).parent().find(".off-canvas-submenu").slideToggle('fast');
            $(this).find("span").text(icon);
});
```

Made it worked this way using `.find()`, you will need to style the `.off-canvas-submenu` since its not on the same level as the other elements anymore therefor not inheriting the style of first level `<ul>` but in all you should me good.

**Edit:**

Works with multiple submenu

```
<aside class="left-off-canvas-menu">
    <ul class="off-canvas-list">
        <li><label>Foundation</label></li>
        <li><a href="#">Option 1</a></li>
        <li>
            <a href="#" class="off-canvas-submenu-call">Option 2 <span class="right"> + </span></a>
            <ul class="off-canvas-submenu">
                <li><a href="#">Sub menu 1</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Sub menu 2</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Sub menu 3</a></li>
            </ul>
        </li>
       <li>
            <a href="#" class="off-canvas-submenu-call">Option 3 <span class="right"> + </span></a>
            <ul class="off-canvas-submenu">
                <li><a href="#">Sub menu 1</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Sub menu 2</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Sub menu 3</a></li>
            </ul>
        </li>
    </ul>
</aside>
```